# Unable to send PHP email via amazon EC2

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2

My website is running on AWS ec2 server with php forms. I installed and used sendmail as an SMTP but it won't working. I am running mail as default and after few emails it got stop (seems like my ip address is blocked). Kindly give me some good solutions to run php emails on aws ec2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using aws free tier then you have to subscribe to SES - Amazon Simple Email Service (https://aws.amazon.com/ses/). I too faced this problem.

Comment: Yes, I knw this but seems like I am unable to implement the SES service. Is there any guide or tutorial for the same. + Can we increase the daily email limits to higher ?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ses/ @gurupalsingh